# K - means clustering - visualize for multiple class

Tags: r, clustering, data-visualization

I clustered seperate dataset containing data from different classes. 
I want visualize all the clusters in one plot to see how much they overlap or if they even do overlap.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [How to plot clusters in more than 3 dimensions?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/173820/1352)

Comment: Not exactly..  so 10 classes => is just data of handwriting digits 0-9.

I have separated the dataset such  that 
datasetX only contains data related to the digit x. 

I've have then clustered each datasetX with kmeans, which has given me a lot of clustered. 

Now i want to see how well each cluster are separated amongst each class, visually

Comment: This question seems rather broad and lacks focus at the moment. The distance matrix seems separate from the visual plot you want in the first paragraph; is it essentially a code request? If so, that would generally be off-topic here, have a look at our [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Silver I agree that "retrieve a distance matrix" is a matter of coding. It also might be irrelevant: one can imagine creative answers that avoid using the full distance matrix but instead (say) project the points into two or three dimensions or otherwise visualize them to address the intended purpose.  On the basis of the first paragraph of the question, then, I vote to keep it open.

Comment: ... I hope it make sense now..